# Circuit step-by-step check

Tags: circuit-analysis, guitar-pedal

I've soldered a stompbox for guitar and stuck into having no sound on the output. Visually I checked everything about the soldering and it seems good. As I am not so good at electronics I wish getting any help on how to  step-by-step check the place where there could be a trouble using multimeter  or some another methods. [image: Schematic]

UPD:[image: Actual schematic]

Comment: Schematic where?

Comment: Post photos of the top & bottom of your actual board. Maybe someone will see a mistake.

Comment: The TL061 series needs a bipolar power supply. Its range is +/- 5 volts to +/- 15 volts. 9 vdc is not enough for this op-amp to even turn on and be stable. Check the datasheets.

Comment: This schematic is also missing bypass capacitors on the power pins of the op-amp. This is a poor design for a wide-band low noise op-amp.

Comment: @Sparky256 - Hi. Re "The TL061 series needs a bipolar power supply" - that doesn't seem to be the whole story; from [TI TL061 datasheet, p15](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/tl062.pdf) "This device can be operated as a single supply operational amplifier [...]". Also "Its range is +/- 5 volts to [...]" is not such a clear lower limit. I have found old TI docs which state the lower limit is +/- 3.5 V (i.e. a single supply of 7 V) and an [ST datasheet](http://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/tl061.pdf) which shows +/-2 V in figures 3 & 6 on p7. Fully agree about the bypass caps, but [...]

Comment: @SamGibson. Good point Sam. If the power was 12vdc or more, there is a trick of connecting a 10K resistor from the output pin 6 to Vcc. The offset current will bias the IC into operating with only a slight positive offset at the output. Not sure if it will work with only 8 volts though.

Comment: [...] considering a [similar circuit](http://www.electrosmash.com/mxr-microamp) is apparently in commercial production, my initial view would be that there is some evidence that the op-amp will work in that design. The photos requested already by *brhans* (which need to be good quality, in focus and close-up, of course) should help give us some clues about whether voltage measurements are needed, or whether other problems are more obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow the signal path.

Start where you apply signal,  the input, and check if there is the signal actually is what you expect.
Then follow the signal path and search where it disappear. Here is the fault.

Oscilloscope is a great help for this type of task.